# html element caputre using html2canvas error

Tags: javascript, screen, html2canvas, capture, mediapipe

Hi I'm making a code using mediapipe javascript and I want to capture the output canvas
which has the landmarks and line, so I'm trying to use html2canvas but I'm having some errors could you guys help me or give me other solutions? As a result I want the capture the image and store it in sessionStorage or firestore and show it on the next html page.

This is the part where the html elements are.
the output_canvas is where the mediapipe landmarks are shown.
When I run this code I get the error of typeerror: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toDataURL')

```
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <div class = "ui-element" id="angle21"></div>
      <div class="ui-element" id = "clock"></div>
      <div class="ui-element" id = "clock2"></div>
      <video class="input_video"></video>
      <canvas class="output_canvas" width="1280px" height="720px"></canvas>
      <div class="landmark-grid-container"></div>  

  </div>
</body>
```

And this is the script part where I use the html2canvas

```
const takeScreenShot = async () => {
        //const screenshotTarget = document.body;
        var screenshotTarget = document.querySelector('.output_canvas');
        // document.querySelectorAll('.ui-element').forEach(element => {
        //   element.style.display = 'none'
        // })
        //var screenshotTarget=document.querySelector('.output_canvas');
        
        const canvas = html2canvas(screenshotTarget, {
          allowTaint:true,
          foreignObjectRendering: true
        });
        console.log(canvas)
        const base64image = canvas[1].toDataURL();
        window.location.href = base64image;
        // document.querySelectorAll('.ui-element').forEach(element => {
        //   element.style.display = 'block'
        // })
      }
setTimeout(async () => {
       await takeScreenShot()
      }, 1000 * 8)
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski When I run this code I get the error of typeerror: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toDataURL')

Comment: What is this `[1]` suppose to do here? `canvas[1]`